# Getter function with switch case?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public User getByField(string field, string stringToFilter)
{
    string fieldToReturn;
    switch (field)
    {
        case "id":
            fieldToReturn = "u.pk_user_id";
            break;
        case "username":
            fieldToReturn = "u.user_username";
            break;
    }

    var result = (from u in dc.Users
                  where fieldToReturn == stringToFilter
                  select fieldToReturn).Single();
    return result;
}
```

I am trying to create one getter for all my fields using a switch case, because otherwise I would have to create a lot of setters (There are more cases than displayed here). But when I try to return the result, it says it is a String, rather than a User. I suppose it is because I am using a String in the LINQ-query, but I've tried solving it but can't figure it out how to do.

Comment: 'select u' instead of 'fieldToReturn' ?

Comment: Please post the code for User

Answer (score 5):

In [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), the author explains how you can achieve operations like yours using the [Dynamic Query Library (download)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Create a Func with a parameter of User and returns a bool. Then you create this Func based on which field you need to use. When you call the where, pass this Func created.

```
public User getByField(string field, string stringToFilter)
{
    Func<User, bool> wherePred = null;
    switch (field)
    {
        case "id":
            wherePred = u => u.pk_user_id == stringToFilter;
            break;
        case "username":
            wherePred = u => u.user_username == stringToFilter;
            break;
    }

    var result = dc.Users.Where(wherePred).Single();
    return result;
}
```